# How to pass parameters between Applet classes in Java with Processing

Tags: java, applet, processing

I have four coordinates saved in the main class as global Variables. How do I access getters or give parameters to the new Applet? It isn't possible to create an instance because the values of the main class are getting set before the code of the second Applet is run.
When the mouse is pressed and when its released the positions are saved in my main Applet. By releasing the mouse button a second Applet in another Java Class gets opened.
The goal is second Applet being the size of the rectangle the mouse just dragged.

```
public void mousePressed() {
        setStartDetectionAreaX(mouseX);
        setStartDetectionAreaY(mouseY);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(){
        setEndDetectionAreaX(mouseX);
        setEndDetectionAreaY(mouseY);
        PApplet.main("SecondWindow");
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to provide a detailed answer, however I suggest you start with **Processing > Examples > Demos > Tests > MultipleWindows** and begin to tweak remove code you don't need for your task to undertand it then convert / apply that understanding to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found a solution. It it possible to give a String Array as a parameter while calling the other Applet.
Like this:

```
PApplet.main("SecondWindow", new String[]{pm1, pm2, pm3, pm4};
```

In the other class its know possible to get the array like this:

```
args[0]
```

Another possibility would be setting a static variable and change it in the other class.